# Не импортируется TabLayout

Tags: java, android-sdk, android

При попытке написать:

`TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);`

выскакивает ошибка:

> TabLayout cannot be resolved to a type

Что делать?

Вот полный код:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_for_tabs_1);

        TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));

        tabLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50));

        v.addView(tabLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: библиотека support:design подключена к проекту и если да, то как?

Comment: @pavlofff, ух ты! А что это за такая библиотека? :D

Comment: @bukashka101 это библиотека, коя содержит нужный вам класс. Без неё компилироваться не будет ваш код.

Comment: Вам надо подключить библиотеку к проекту.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как ее подключить? ``import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;`` — не работает. Пишет: The import android.support.design cannot be resolved

Comment: Вам надо не импортировать класс в класс, а подключить библиотеку у проекту.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а не подскажите, как ее подключить? Ну или где лежит нужный мне .jar файл. P.S. Я пользуюсь Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас не подключена библиотека `support:design`.

Чтобы подключить библиотеку в `Eclipse`:

1. Скачайте её через `SDK Manager`
2. в Eclipse - New->Android_project_from_existing_code
3. Ищем в папке ПУТЬ_К ПАПКЕ_SDK\extras\android\support\design
4. Помечаем библиотекой его
5. Подключаем к основному проекту (Свойства->Android->Libraries->Add)

Comment: А как "пометить библиотекой его"?

Comment: Свойства->Android->IsLibrary(галочку проставить)

Comment: Теперь, в строке ``LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_for_tabs_1);`` выдает ошибку "R cannot be resolved to a variable" :(. И чем плох вариант тупо закинуть .jar в libs?

Comment: Проверьте в свойствах подключенной либы для какой версии API она собирается (лучше максимальную поставить), Проверьте, подключена ли таким же образом support-v7 либа, Импортируйте R.

Comment: ``LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) R.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_for_tabs_1);`` — тоже не работает (если я вас правильно понял). Стоит для API 4.0.3, так как я собираю приложения для 4.0.3.

Comment: Проставьте максимум таки. По крайней мере для меня это решало проблему. После этого (и предыдущего коммента) должно заработать.

Comment: Не хочет :(. На строке ``TabLayout tabLayout = new TabLayout(this);`` вылетает, если тупо закидывать .jar в libs. А если путем добавления библиотеки, который описали Вы — приложение дохнет на ``LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) R.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_for_tabs_1);``

Comment: Просто jar недостаточно - нужны ресурсы к библиотеке, так что только проектом подключать. Что значит "дохнет"? Падает после запуска или не компилируется?

Comment: Ладно, вернусь к ``Tab``, а с ``TabLayout`` буду разбираться, когда дойду до библиотеки design.

Comment: Не компилируется. Ошибка "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Ну и зря) Погуглите как подключать библиотеки - там всё не так сложно как кажется.

Comment: Пройдите ещё раз весь путь, указанный в ответе и комментах.

Comment: Все равно упаду, когда дойдет до изменения этих кнопок, обработок их действия и тд. Не буду на столько лезть вперед Я вообще на 44 уроке startandroid, а сам лезу к Tab'aм и TableLayout...

Comment: Я несколько раз прошел — ничего не меняется :(.

Comment: Ну, мне больше нечего предложить - я делал как описывал и всё работало.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете AndroidStudio, то:

в Gradle Scripts, в `build.gradle(Module: app`)  добавить в `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:хх.х.х'
```

`хх.х.х` - версия твоих используемых библиотек.
После - синхронизировать!

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Форматирование кода - 4 пробела перед строкой. Там ещё кнопки есть в редакторе.